# cant connect to database and choose a database

Tags: asp.net, database

I installed adventure works, and I followed the instructions on this page:

[How to: Create Connections to SQL Server Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4yys16a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

basically nothing appears in the drop down, in step 2.

I cant even attach the database without getting an error, nor drag it to the web form.

It tells me that the database cant be attached cause it is version 705, and the server supports version 655..

Also what is teh difference between attaching the database and connecting to it?

I went to the installation center of 2008, and clicked on show installation info..I got this:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Setup Discovery Report
> Product Instance    Instance ID Feature Language    Edition Version Clustered
> Sql Server 2008 SQLEXPRESS  MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS  Database Engine Services
>
> 1033    Express Edition 10.1.2531.0 No Sql Server
> 2008  SQLEXPRESS  MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS  SQL Server Replication  1033    Express
> Edition   10.1.2531.0 No

so I guess it is installed on my computer, but I cant access the application

Answer (score 1):

You need the database to exist in an instance of SQL Server (or whatever RDBMS you so choose...but most likely, SQL Server).  To do this you can do a few things:  namely restore a *.bak database backup file of AdventureWorks, or you can attached the mdf and ldf files (database data and log files) to get your database online.

> basically nothing appears in the drop down

Do you have an instance of SQL Server installed on your machine?

> Also what is teh difference between attaching the database and connecting to it?

Attaching the database is using mdf and ldf files to get your database online ready for transactions.  Connecting to the database is creating a connection between a client application and the aforementioned database.  Two very different steps of the data access process.

Comment: isnt it installed automatically with visual studio 2010 ultimate?

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd Yes, it is.  Just type in "localhost" or "." for servername then if you aren't using an external SQL Server instance.  SQL Server express by default has an instance name of `ServerName\SQLEXPRESS`.  So you may have to use "localhost\sqlexpress".

Comment: what is the difference between attaching and connecting..it terms of performance and execution?!?

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd attaching is configuration to get your database ready and online.  Connecting is an application accessing the database.

Comment: The database doesnt appear in the "Select database name" drop down..only master,model, msdb, tempdb... and is there any disadvantages with attaching a database?

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd Did you restore/attach your database in the instance?  Those are all system databases that ship with the instance.

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd When you open up SQL Server Management Studio and connect to the instance, what DBs do you see?

Comment: the problem is that i havent got the SQL Server management studio installed only SQL server installation center.. and when I click on install new standalone sql server, it tells me to browse to SQL server media 2008... I dont know where it wants me to browse and why it doesnt install automatically the management studio

Comment: I have the adventureworks in this folder: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data

Comment: I am going to try to download it from here : http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7593.. I dont know if it helps

Answer (score 1):

Attaching to a database is necessary when the database file(s) are in a location other than the default location.  You don't really "connect" to a specific database per se.  You connect to a sql server instance which contains a list of databases on that instance (or referenced by the instance).

Comment: Basically, just attach the database.  In server management studio, right-click on "DATABASES", select "ATTACH", click "ADD" and navigate to the mdf file location and select it.  Hope this helps.